# QR код с определением устройства

Tags: qrcode

Появилась потребность в генерации (одноразовой) QR кода который умел бы определять устройство и в зависимости от того каким устройством он был считан, перенаправлять по определенной ссылке. Кто-то сталкивался с таким?

Comment: "каким устройством" с точностью до чего?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю достаточно определять платформу.

Answer (score 2):

`QR Code` просто картинка с зашифрованной в ней информацией, сама она никуда и никого не перенаправляет.

Можно сгенерировать `QR Code` с определенной информацией, например, адрес в сети (url), но то, что программа, которая распознала `QR Code` будет делать с этой информацией зависит только от нее.

---

Например, я взял случайный сайт генерации `QR Code` из гугла, выбрал тип `URL` (от типа будут зависеть предлагаемые поля в форме, для URL это будет проверка что введен адрес сети) и ввел туда строку "https://www.google.ru/", он мне сгенерировал:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал считать эту картинку из приложения на телефоне, приложение поняло, что там ссылка и предложило перейти по указанному адресу.

Попробовал считать эту картинку из [сайта](https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx), тот распознал и даже смог определить тип информации и все:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Окей, мне нужно 2 разные ссылки, допустим на гугл плей и на апл стор, это можно как-то реализовать?

Comment: В одной QR Code? Или в разных?

Comment: да, в нем родимом

Comment: Генерите QR-код со ссылкой на свой сайт. На сайте определяете устройство и редиректите в нужный стор

Comment: Ну или используйте сторонний сервис. Их много https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=qr+code+link+to+different+stores&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Разве что делать страницу, на которой фронтендом уже будет определяться ОС и показываться/редиректиться нужная ссылка.